# Is it possible to create a Mac-Based Distro?

Tags: macbook-pro

ElemenataryOS is a linux distro.

But I like things like Hammerspoon. Is it possible to make an OSx distro? With custom stuff like custom apps installed?

Then I can re-install things quickly on all my OS devices.

Comment: Are you after an MDM solution or a simple disk clone? There's no such thing as a ready-made installer + extras.

Comment: No, I have a bunch of custom software that I want on the machine.

Comment: I also might distirbute it to people. Like some people use Ubuntu. They might also want to use ElemenataryOS.

Comment: It is unlawful to distribute macOS. Only Apple can, lawfully, do that. You can make an image of your preferred, customized macOS with everything you want on it and nothing you don't. *For your own use.* But you can't distribute it.

Comment: Then why do they pre-package the `asr` library?

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Apple delivers the `asr` command which is called from the graphical Disk Utility to clone user data into a disk image. There are other tools like Carbon Copy Cloner and SuperDuper that do similar and extra tricks for backup and cloning.

You can delete the user accounts and home folders and also remove the AppleSetupDone file to get a new system boot if you prefer that.

As long as you’re running licensed macOS on hardware that’s correct for the version, imaging is something you can do. Others also automate tools like `brew` so you can dump on .dotfiles and install apps by recipe instead of by imaging.

You will want to get a lawyer to read the license if you are distributing software as opposed to scripts or methods to automate things. Laws and licenses vary and most people need lawyers to know if local laws make licenses more or less effective.

https://www.apple.com/legal/sla/

Comment: Neat! Am having a look now!

Comment: Hmm, is there a good tutorial on how to use it?